# oracle sequence of queries based on if condition

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql, oracle11g

how can i automate to execute last three queries if output of my first query is "0" ?

My queries are as below:

**1**. First query of which output should be '0':

`select pages from feature_control;`

**2**. If output of above query is '0', then auto execute below three
    queries:

```
alter trigger feature_control disable;  
alter trigger rep_feature_control disable;  
update feature_control set pages = '0';
```

Comment: What is your question? PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as tabular initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap DDL statements by `execute immediate '...'`  :

```
declare
  v_pages  feature_control.pages%type;
begin
 begin
    select pages into v_pages from feature_control;
  exception when no_data_found then pages='-1'; --just a presumed value other than null or zero.
 end;

 if v_pages = '0' then
    execute immediate 'alter trigger feature_control disable';  
    execute immediate 'alter trigger rep_feature_control disable';  
    update feature_control set pages = v_pages;
    commit;
 end if;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

"Automatically" can't be done "automagically", but a (stored or anonymous PL/SQL) procedure might help. Here's how.

Setup first:

```
SQL> create table feature_control (pages varchar2(1));

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger feature_control
  2    before insert on feature_control
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    null;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> create or replace trigger rep_feature_control
  2    before insert on feature_control
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    null;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into feature_control(pages) values ('0');

1 row created.
```

Now, using dynamic SQL - as DDL can't be executed directly - do something like this:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_pages feature_control.pages%type;
  3  begin
  4    select pages into l_pages
  5      from feature_control;
  6
  7    if l_pages = '0' then
  8       execute immediate 'alter trigger     feature_control disable';
  9       execute immediate 'alter trigger rep_feature_control disable';
 10       update feature_control set pages = '0';
 11    end if;
 12  end;
 13  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Though, I don't see much sense in that as the only affect is that two triggers will be disabled. The `pages` column value was `'0'` anyway, otherwise that code wouldn't have been executed at all. Also, the whole example means that `feature_control` table is supposed to contain a single row (otherwise that `select` would return `too-many-rows` or `no-data-found`).

Anyway, that's how you might have done it. See if it helps.

Comment: OK then, I'm glad if it helped.